# Faster Android emulation on Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, android-emulator, xamarin.android

Previously, I was using the Xamarin Android Player, which is now [deprecated](https://blog.xamarin.com/live-from-dotnetconf-cycle-7-xamarin-studio-6-and-more/). This was the fastest Android emulator I've used in recent times, so I was somewhat confused to hear it was deprecated. Now, I'm attempting to use Android's SDK emulator with Intel's [HAXM](https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager) (latest version 6.0.3). I'm using the SDK's image for x86 (previously tried x86_64 image) for Android 7/N (API 24). I'm also using an older system (Apple's Macbook 2011 Core 2 Duo running Mac OS X 10.11), so I'm sure that might play a part in the slowness. I can never get the emulator to boot beyond the android loading animation (the one that says android).

Does anyone have any recommendations on getting the emulator to run well on a mac?

Comment: Genymotion is the best emulator i've been using for years.

Comment: I was looking at Genymotion, but I haven't found any documentation on pushing builds from Xamarin to Genymotion.

Comment: Just need to install it a Xamarin studio will recognize it.

Comment: Trying this tonight then @jzeferino. Have you gotten the SDK-based emulator to run? Mine never loads and takes hours before it gets to the boot animation.

Comment: Forget that, just install Genymotion, create a device and run it. Then just deploy from xamarin studio.

Comment: i have had great luck, and good speeds, with the newest Google emulators. Make sure you have updated the emulators and system images in your Android SDK Manager to get the latest version of Google's Android emulators.

Comment: @Scorpius I have seen your exact issue on MacBooks w/ *Core 2 Duo** using Intel's Haxm (2/4gb allocated out of 8/16GB system based ram). I spent WAY to many cycles looking into it, reviewing hundreds/thousands of logcat entries and in the end it just does **not** work consistently. On that CPU (and some others), VBox based emulators (Genymotion, Bluestacks, etc..) and Parallels/Vmware based Android i386 distros seem to be the only workable option.

Comment: @Scorpius I posted this yesterday : https://twitter.com/PlayScriptRedux/status/754583566969741312

Comment: Unfortunately, the question still stands. Genymotion crashes when I open it. I'll have to look for more help on that somewhere. Qemu never boots beyond android animation. Guess it might be time for a new computer.

Comment: I personally prefer to debug on a real device if you have android device. This is the fastest and better way. Emulator and device is also very often different in action. Especially I hate to use all those VMs to run an emulator. they slow down my debugging experience.

Comment: @batmaci I too prefer to use a device, but I only have so many devices (of my own) to test. An emulator allows me to test a number of different scenarios with various AVDs. I have installed and tried genymotion, but the latest version does not work (crashes). I tried an older version that worked, but my builds did not push to the emulator.